# how to store hashmap in cassandra table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, hashmap

I have a hashmap as shown below

```
Map(351608084641351 -> List(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.547012087E9, 85.099209, 25.578898, 0.0), 351608087410838 -> List(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.547013043E9, 74.356467, 22.301069, 0.0))
```

I want columns "id", "d1","d2","d3","d4","evt","lt","ln","s"

`key` 351608084641351 of hashmap is id column.

`List(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.547012087E9, 85.099209, 25.578898, 0.0)` is 
`"d1","d2","d3","d4","evt","lt","ln","s"` respectively

I want to store this hashmap into a cassandra table as described above.

I am able to access the values and key of this hashmap but not able to find ways to store it in cassandra
My hashmap is :
HashMap[Long,List[Any]]

output required
table as :

```
id d1 d2 d3 d4 evt lt ln s
351608084641351 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.547012087E9 85.099209 25.578898 0.0
```

Comment: are you using datastax cassandra driver?

Comment: @RamanMishra yes

Answer (score 0):

you can use method .setMap on the boundStatement.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConvertors._

val statement = session.prepare(s"insert into $XYZ ($MAP) values (:$MAP)")
val map: Map[lang.Long, util.List[lang.Double]] = Map(long2Long(351608084641351) -> List(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.547012087E9, 85.099209, 25.578898, 0.0).map(num=> double2Double(num)).asJava)
val boundStatement = statement.bind
boundStatement.setMap("Column Name", map.asJava, classOf[java.lang.Long], classOf[java.util.List[java.lang.Double]]])
```

As the DataStax driver is of java to set map we need to convert out scalaMap into java map using JavaConvertors. Also we need to use the Java data types for our key and value As I can see you have Long as your key and List as your value so you will have to convert them into `java.lang.Long` and `Java.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>` by using methond `long2Long` and `double2Double`.

After binding the statement you can execute it should get saved into the database.

Given that your map has the same data types as provided in the ClassOf parameter. that means either you can give the same data type for you map or you will have to convert them from scala to java.

Comment: my hashmap is HashMap[Long,List[Any]]

Comment: I think Object can take any kind of type in Java

Comment: it gives an error type mismatch; found : (Long, List[Any]) required: Double,in val map line

Comment: I have given list of double as the value of the map but it seems you have list of any change it to list of any it will work

Comment: what does this stand for?($MAP) values (:$MAP)

Comment: @experiment these are constant for the column name in the table xyz we use s string interpolation to use variable in the string using $ this sign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186443/discussion-between-experiment-and-raman-mishra).